# ABAP : Reading itab and displaying it's values

Tags: abap

I have the following ABAP program.
The program splits a line of text by space and fills variables and an internal table itab.
How to read the internal table in a loop and display it's values.

```
REPORT  z_test110.
DATA: str1 TYPE string,
      str2 TYPE string,
      str3 TYPE string,
      itab TYPE TABLE OF string,
      text TYPE string,
      wa LIKE LINE OF itab.

text = `Where do you want to go today`.

SPLIT text AT space INTO: str1 str2 str3,
                          TABLE itab.
```

Comment: `LOOP AT itab INTO DATA(line)`? I think we could use some more information about your target... also your ABAP Version could be useful

Comment: As @Achuth hadnoor's comment shows, you can read the internal table and display its values only using the `itab` and `wa` variables. Were the variables `str1`, `str2`, and `str3` relevant to your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
LOOP AT itab INTO wa.
WRITE:/ wa.
ENDLOOP.
```

hey i tried the program and you can use this code it works perfectly.
still feeling issues comment here!